# MongoDB doesn't insert a second document into a collection (C# Driver)

Tags: c#, mongodb, insert

I wrote a little tool to try out MongoDB with.
It generates a class that nests a random amount of subclasses and sub-subclasses (within certain bounds, of course), so I have some data.

When I try to insert the data into a collection, it works for the first time, when the collection is being created. Whenever I try to insert another instance of this class in this existing collection, nothing happens. No exception is being thrown and the mongo server doesn't appear to do anything.

```
    public WriteConcernResult InsertData(MyClass instance, string collection)
    {
        if (DbDatabase.GetCollection(collection) != null)
        {
            WriteConcernResult result;

            try
            {
                result = DbDatabase.GetCollection(collection).Insert(instance);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                result = null;
            }

            return result;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Am I using this wrong? How can I find out what happens to the data?

edit: This is the result of the WriteConcernResult:

> { "ok" : 1, "n" : NumberLong(0) }

Comment: Can't tell. Not enough code here to show what you are actually doing. Edit please.

Comment: Sorry, added some more of that test method.

Comment: is your key auto generated, or a custom key?

Comment: By the way, my class does not feature an _id field. I let MongoDB handle that.

Comment: So, auto generated key.

Comment: It's hard to tell what's wrong, could you post the piece of code that calls the InsertData method? And maybe a portion of MyClass' definition.

Answer (score 0):

There still isn't enough code provided to answer your question. Can you provide a standalone sample that reproduces the problem?

For example, the following standalone program correctly inserts two documents. Can you try modifying it to reproduce what you are seeing?

```
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost");
        var server = client.GetServer();
        var database = server.GetDatabase("test");
        var collection = database.GetCollection("test");

        collection.Drop();
        collection.Insert(new BsonDocument("_id", 1));
        collection.Insert(new BsonDocument("_id", 2));
    }
}
```